# java web service jax-ws client authentication Tomcat not working

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, ssl

I have the following client that consumes web service that is running on tomcat (local host)

Client

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;

public class NewClass {
    static {
        //for localhost testing only
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
        new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){
            public boolean verify(String hostname,
                    javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                if (hostname.equals("localhost")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         System.out.println(receive(5));

    }
    private static java.util.List<java.lang.Object> receive(int resNumber) {

       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","c:\\mylocalhost.jks"); //path to jks
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","****"); //path to jks
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","c:\\myclient.jks"); //path to jks
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","*****"); //path to jks
       System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");

       client.NewWebService_Service service = new client.NewWebService_Service();
       client.NewWebService port = service.getNewWebServicePort();
       java.util.Map<String,Object> rmap = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
       java.util.Map<String,List<String>> header= new HashMap();
       header.put("Username", Collections.singletonList("1"));
       header.put("Password", Collections.singletonList("1"));

       rmap.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS , header);
       rmap.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"https://localhost:8443/WSTest1/NewWebService");
      return port.receiveData(resNumber);

    }

}
```

Now on tomcat I have the following in server.xml

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" 

              keystoreFile="conf/mytomcatkeystore.jks" clientAuth="false"  scheme="https" secure="true" 
               />
```

and I am using following options to start tomcat

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=file:///c:/mylocalhost.jks" "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=****" "-Djavax.net.debug=all"
```

Now, web service call over ssl works fine when `clientAuth="false"` however if 
I set `clientAuth="true"` in server.xml I get the following error.

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Tried to search for solution on many sites - with no luck. 
If somebody can help - will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O.K. After many frustrating hours, I finally found the solution, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362588/mutual-authentication-with-tomcat-7) SO post.

So the solution was to **comment out**  the following line inside the `server.xml`

`<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is about the https communication. The client don't specify that it wants to communicate over https. Take a look at this [Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception)

Comment: However, I am using - `"https://localhost:8443/WSTest1/NewWebService"`, how else would some one specify that communication is over https ? Also,    ssl works fine without client authentication ...

Comment: Ok . From the tomcat documentation that is the meaning of the attribute **clientAuth** : Set to true if you want the SSL stack to require a valid certificate chain from the client before accepting a connection. etc... http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html. So it's not about a valid combination of user/pwd...

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to achieve - to authenticate client using it's (self signed) certificate .... so far no luck though :-(

Comment: And by the way, don't be confused by the username and password inside the header, it has nothing to do with the problem I am facing ...